# How to give more weight for title than other fields in Mysql Full Text Search Index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am implementing mysql full text search, here I am facing one issue, results displaying but not working as I expect. When I perform search for 'Samsung Galaxy S6' it is coming at second position. I need title has more weight than other fields.

If search string in title found, it will come first, and one more thing when I perform only with "S6" results are strange 0 results showing, how should I do this. Please help.

My [Sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0549/14)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide an answer to the weighting of results if the search term was found in the title. I can provide the reason as to why searching for just "S6" returns 0 results, this is a MySQL limitation, where it's minimum word length is 4 characters by default, this can be changed in my.ini, look for the `ft_min_word_len` (and inversely `ft_max_word_len`).

This is assuming you're using the `MATCH()` of course.

Further reading: [MySQL Natural Language Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: Thank You for your advice. I will change.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply a different weight for the fields text and title, you have to create an separate index on each column. Then you use both indices with a weight factor.

```
select *
from mytable
where match(title) against 'word' 
    or match(text) against 'word' 
order by 
    2 * match(title) against 'word' 
    + match(text) against 'word' 
    desc
```

Choose an appropriate weighing factor (2 might be good).

Comment: results same samsung s6 is at second position

Comment: select * from products where MATCH(title) AGAINST ('samsung galaxy s6') OR match(tags) AGAINST ('samsung galaxy s6') ORDER BY 2 * match(title) AGAINST ('samsung galaxy s6') + match(tags) AGAINST ('samsung galaxy s6') desc

Comment: Looking in your sql fiddle shows that the first 4 rows have an identical relevance. 'S6' is not taken in account, only 'Samsung Galaxy' is. You have to combine my answer and James' if you want to get a distinction between 'Samsung Galaxy' and 'Samsung Galaxy S6'.